# Mongoose Koa.js : `await` does not wait untill `exec` of Mongoose is complete.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, koa, koa2

I'm using latest Koa.js with Mongoose.

I'm using Mongoose's `exec` to transform the data before it is sent out as response.
I find that whenever I use `exec`, it does not wait for the `exec` to complete before sending out the response and that the `exec` gets completed after the response is sent out.

How can I fix this?

The following is my code.

*Route code:*

```
 router.post("/", async ctx=>{
    console.log("data route");
    const datas = await controller.get();
    console.log("AFTER data get", datas);
    ctx.body = datas;
});
```

*Controller code:*

```
exports.get = async ()=>{
    console.log("data get");
    return await dataModel.find().lean().exec(function(err, docs){
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        console.log("inside exec");
        docs = new DataClass(docs);
        console.log(docs);
    });
};
```

The console log gets printed like so:

```
data route
data get
AFTER data get undefined
inside exec
[{name:"test1"}, {name:"test2"}]
```

Comment: PS I've found .exec() does nothing in combination with await. Not sure what the purpose of it is

Comment: @DominicTobias see my answer: `exec` only returns a promise if no callback is provided.

Comment: @Darkhogg what I meant is that using await without `exec` also works perfectly well, e.g. `await dataModel.find().lean();`

Comment: @DominicTobias If I recall correctly, `await` works without it because queries have a compatible `then` method, but for anything where you need a true promise you de need `exec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing promises (`await`) with callbacks, which Mongoose doesn't support.  Remove your callback and use only promises:

```
exports.get = async () => {
    console.log("data get");

    const docs = await dataModel.find().lean().exec()

    console.log("after exec");
    const dataDocs = new DataClass(docs);

    console.log(dataDocs);
    return dataDocs;
};
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I got mixed up! Updated your code to replace `const` with `let` so that it is the variable becomes assignable.

Comment: @TempO'rary I've modified your edit to use a new variable instead. I tend to use `const` unless I absolutely need to use `let`, and this is such a case where `let` is not absolutely needed.